# How to simulate a call so that the bluetooth audio get streamed into a vehicle?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-bluetooth

The iphone connects to most vehicles via bluetooth. Phone calls as well as voice control and siri also get routed via the bluetooth audio and mic of the vehicle.

How can i stream audio in the same way?

I have sen answers about the vehicle capability to support streaming audio, but this is not what i am looking for.  If siri and voice control can stream over the vehicle audio as it is treated as a voice call then i should be able to stream everything else.

Thank you

Comment: Those applications are made by Apple, it wouldn't surprise me if they have more rights than your application. With this i'm not saying it's impossible, just a heads-up.

Comment: What you described is a "virtual call" and is a subject for debate within the Bluetooth industry. It has many corner cases and IOT issues with certain devices, and is not guaranteed to work 100%. The major problem it is designed to solve is that certain car kits would ignore the audio channel (SCO) when a call is not active. And scenarios like Siri are common with car kits. But if your target scenario is mostly with headsets, you shouldn't have to worry about that too much. HFP would work usually pretty well with headsets as most of them honor the SCO audio channel without a phone call.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to simulate a call originated from your iPhone, as opposed to some other device that pretends to be a phone and pairs with your car. You can’t, because Apple doesn’t provide APIs to do that.

Comment: So to confirm.. we are 100% sure that Apple does not provide API for using the bluetooth in the same way they use it for Siri and other native applications? This would be the answer.. if it is.. but I don't want to just close it and give up.

Comment: Yes. Could you describe the underlying problem you are trying to solve? For example, what is the source of the audio you are trying to play—arbitrary audio from any app, or audio generated from inside an app you design? And why can’t you use A2DP?

Answer (score 0):

I think that false.

Google did it.
They do it in Google Search. If you search using voice, it streams simulating a call.

Something similar happens with the voice notes application from Apple. You can stream music to the car as if it was a call.

Actually, my car doesn't support A2DP, only calls, and using voice notes I can play music (odd, but works).

But..., how can we implement it???